# Producer producing data every one second and Consumer consuming after every minute

Tags: c#, multithreading, producer-consumer

I am trying to write a program using BlockingCollection producer/ consumer pattern where producer will keep on producing data every one second and consumer consuming it and displaying some processed data from my Producer data on console window every 60 seconds.

The real life scenario is - I will be getting Open High Low Close stock data in the producer every second which I would like to pass to consumer threads which would create 1 minute OHLC data from 60 seconds data which I will receive from third party. For simulating real life scenario, I am trying to create a producer which would have timer which would keep on putting data in BlockingCollection every second but not sure how to use timer in the producer. Can anyone suggest with code

1. How would I create Producer which would keep on producing OHLC data every second using timer inside the producer. Lets say my OHLC value would have counter which I will be using for counting second. For example
   O=1,H=1,L=1,C=1
   O=2,H=2,L=2,C=2
   ....
   O=60,H=60,L=60,C=60

As soon as the counter reaches multiple of 60, my Consumer should kick-in which would take that 60 second data to create one minute OHLC data.
2. Where would CompleteAdding method be written as my Producer is never ending Producer which will only be stopped once I stop entire application

Any help in this regard is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: Sounds like a job for Reactive Extensions

Comment: @TheGeneral yes, if you can afford the learning curve!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this example two tasks are created: producer and consumer. In the first, data is generated every second and placed in the collection. In the second, the data is extracted from the collection and processed every minute.

```
var produced = new BlockingCollection<Price>();

var producer = Task.Run(async () =>
{
    try
    {
        var random = new Random();
        while (true)
        {
            produced.Add(new Price { Low = random.Next(500), High = random.Next(500, 1000) });
            await Task.Delay(1000);
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        produced.CompleteAdding();
    }
});

var consumer = Task.Run(async () =>
{
    const int interval = 60; // seconds
    var values = new List<Price>();

    foreach (var value in produced.GetConsumingEnumerable())
    {
        values.Add(value);

        if (DateTime.UtcNow.Second % interval == 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(values.Average(p => p.High)); // do some work
            values.Clear();
        }
    }
});

Task.WaitAll(producer, consumer);
```

Comment: Works perfectly, this is what I was looking for. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

A [`BlockingCollection`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/collections/thread-safe/blockingcollection-overview) is needed when you want the consumer to be blocked while waiting for available data, or the producer to be blocked while waiting for available space in a limited-capacity queue. In your case you want to be blocked by time, not by availability, so a simpler collection like a [`ConcurrentQueue`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.concurrentqueue-1) should be enough (or even a thread-unsafe `Queue` protected with a locker).

For exiting the loop when the application ends, I suggest that you use [cooperative cancellation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/threading/cancellation-in-managed-threads) with a `CancellationToken`. This way your application will close cleanly.

```
var queue = new ConcurrentQueue<Price>();
var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();

var producer = Task.Run(async () =>
{
    try
    {
        var random = new Random();
        while (true)
        {
            queue.Enqueue(new Price
            {
                Low = random.Next(0, 500),
                High = random.Next(500, 1000)
            });
            await Task.Delay(millisecondsDelay: 1000, cts.Token);
        }
    }
    catch (OperationCanceledException)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Producer Canceled");
    }
});

var consumer = Task.Run(async () =>
{
    try
    {
        var random = new Random();
        while (true)
        {
            await Task.Delay(millisecondsDelay: 60000, cts.Token);
            var prices = queue.DequeueAll();
            Console.Write($"Minute Report");
            Console.Write($", Count: {prices.Count,2}");
            Console.Write($", Low Average: {prices.Average(p => p.Low):#,0.0000}");
            Console.Write($", High Average: {prices.Average(p => p.High):#,0.0000}");
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
    }
    catch (OperationCanceledException)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Consumer Canceled");
    }
});

Console.WriteLine("Press Escape to finish.");
while (true)
{
    var keyInfo = Console.ReadKey(true);
    if (keyInfo.Key == ConsoleKey.Escape) break;
}
cts.Cancel();
Task.WaitAll(producer, consumer);
```

For dequeuing all items from the queue I used the extension method below:

```
public static List<T> DequeueAll<T>(this ConcurrentQueue<T> source)
{
    var list = new List<T>();
    while (source.TryDequeue(out var item))
    {
        list.Add(item);
    }
    return list;
}
```

Sample output:

> Press Escape to finish.
>   Minute Report, Count: 60, Low Average: 209.5405, High Average: 782.2432
>   Minute Report, Count: 59, Low Average: 285.0500, High Average: 714.5500
>   Minute Report, Count: 60, Low Average: 245.5128, High Average: 718.6667
>   Minute Report, Count: 60, Low Average: 259.6154, High Average: 703.6667
>   Minute Report, Count: 59, Low Average: 215.8919, High Average: 735.0811
>   Minute Report, Count: 59, Low Average: 252.7632, High Average: 727.2368
>   Minute Report, Count: 60, Low Average: 288.5833, High Average: 730.6389
>   Producer Canceled
>   Consumer Canceled

Comment: Theodor, your solution is also nice but in real world, my consumer would actually be blocked cause I will be getting tick data for different scrips every second and I am thinking of creating different consumers which would process this tick data. Consumer may not necessarily know when the tick data arrives. I am thinking of creating one consumer per scrip, is it a good approach to create one consumer per scrip thinking I would be processing data for around 200 scrips ? Your solution has certainly given me different approach for same problem though.

Comment: If you want your consumer to be occasionally blocked (waiting for available data) then you should stick with the `BlockingCollection`. After all this class wraps internally a `ConcurrentQueue`. Unfortunately I can't give you advice for the specific question you ask, because I don't know the business domain.

Answer (score -1):

Another approach is to allow the producer to produce values every second and allow the consumer to read the shared buffer only when it contains 60 data elements. This approach removes all direct dependencies between the producer and the consumer. The producer writes to the shared buffer at a rate natural to the producer while the consumer only deals with a batch of 60 data elements.
The following example using Ada illustrates the concept.

```
with Ada.Text_IO;  use Ada.Text_IO;
with Ada.Calendar; use Ada.Calendar;

procedure Main is
   type Index is mod 60;
   type collect is array (Index) of Positive;

   protected Buffer is
      entry Get (Nums : out collect);
      entry Put (Item : in Positive);
   private
      Buf   : collect;
      Next  : Index   := Index'First;
      Count : Natural := 0;
   end Buffer;

   protected body Buffer is
      entry Get (Nums : out collect) when Count = Index'Modulus is
      begin
         Nums  := Buf;
         Count := 0;
      end Get;

      entry Put (Item : in Positive) when Count < Index'Modulus is
      begin
         Buf (Next) := Item;
         Next       := Next + 1;
         Count      := Count + 1;
      end Put;

   end Buffer;

   task producer is
      entry Done;
   end producer;

   task body Producer is
      Cur_Time : Time;
      Pause    : constant Duration := 1.0;
      Count    : Positive          := 1;
   begin
      for Outer in 1 .. 10 loop
         for Inner in 1 .. 60 loop
            Buffer.Put (Count);
            Cur_Time := Clock;
            Count    := Count + 1;
            delay until Cur_Time + Pause;
         end loop;
      end loop;
      accept Done;
   end Producer;

   task Consumer is
      entry Stop;
   end Consumer;

   task body Consumer is
      Batch : collect;
      Sum   : Integer := 0;
   begin
      loop
         select
            accept Stop;
            exit;
         else
            select
               Buffer.Get (Batch);
               Sum := 0;
               for val of Batch loop
                  Put (val'Image);
                  Sum := Sum + val;
               end loop;
               New_Line;
               Put_Line ("Average:" & Integer'Image (Sum / Batch'Length));
            or
               delay 0.01;
            end select;
         end select;
      end loop;
   end Consumer;

begin
   Producer.Done;
   Consumer.Stop;
end Main;
```

The output of this program is:

```
 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60
Average: 30
 61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 70 71 72 73 74 75 76 77 78 79 80 81 82 83 84 85 86 87 88 89 90 91 92 93 94 95 96 97 98 99 100 101 102 103 104 105 106 107 108 109 110 111 112 113 114 115 116 117 118 119 120
Average: 90
 121 122 123 124 125 126 127 128 129 130 131 132 133 134 135 136 137 138 139 140 141 142 143 144 145 146 147 148 149 150 151 152 153 154 155 156 157 158 159 160 161 162 163 164 165 166 167 168 169 170 171 172 173 174 175 176 177 178 179 180
Average: 150
 181 182 183 184 185 186 187 188 189 190 191 192 193 194 195 196 197 198 199 200 201 202 203 204 205 206 207 208 209 210 211 212 213 214 215 216 217 218 219 220 221 222 223 224 225 226 227 228 229 230 231 232 233 234 235 236 237 238 239 240
Average: 210
 241 242 243 244 245 246 247 248 249 250 251 252 253 254 255 256 257 258 259 260 261 262 263 264 265 266 267 268 269 270 271 272 273 274 275 276 277 278 279 280 281 282 283 284 285 286 287 288 289 290 291 292 293 294 295 296 297 298 299 300
Average: 270
 301 302 303 304 305 306 307 308 309 310 311 312 313 314 315 316 317 318 319 320 321 322 323 324 325 326 327 328 329 330 331 332 333 334 335 336 337 338 339 340 341 342 343 344 345 346 347 348 349 350 351 352 353 354 355 356 357 358 359 360
Average: 330
 361 362 363 364 365 366 367 368 369 370 371 372 373 374 375 376 377 378 379 380 381 382 383 384 385 386 387 388 389 390 391 392 393 394 395 396 397 398 399 400 401 402 403 404 405 406 407 408 409 410 411 412 413 414 415 416 417 418 419 420
Average: 390
 421 422 423 424 425 426 427 428 429 430 431 432 433 434 435 436 437 438 439 440 441 442 443 444 445 446 447 448 449 450 451 452 453 454 455 456 457 458 459 460 461 462 463 464 465 466 467 468 469 470 471 472 473 474 475 476 477 478 479 480
Average: 450
 481 482 483 484 485 486 487 488 489 490 491 492 493 494 495 496 497 498 499 500 501 502 503 504 505 506 507 508 509 510 511 512 513 514 515 516 517 518 519 520 521 522 523 524 525 526 527 528 529 530 531 532 533 534 535 536 537 538 539 540
Average: 510
 541 542 543 544 545 546 547 548 549 550 551 552 553 554 555 556 557 558 559 560 561 562 563 564 565 566 567 568 569 570 571 572 573 574 575 576 577 578 579 580 581 582 583 584 585 586 587 588 589 590 591 592 593 594 595 596 597 598 599 600
Average: 570
[2019-11-08 08:57:07] process terminated successfully, elapsed time: 10:05.48s
```